# initctl: Unknown job: couchdb in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, curl, localhost, couchdb, upstart

Installing couchdb in Ubuntu 12.04 in Chromebook via Crouton through this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install -V couchdb
```

I notice this from the reply

```
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
initctl: Unknown job: couchdb
```

Following the instructions from here: https://launchpad.net/~couchdb/+archive/ubuntu/stable

And when I typed on:

```
sudo stop couchdb
```

It replied:

```
stop: Unknown job: couchdb
```

I also tried changing the bind_address from local.ini, yet nothing changed and when I:

```
curl localhost:5984
```

It replied:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I don't know what's wrong with this really since I'm still new with couchDB but I'm really willing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Upstart on the host (Chrome OS) is occupying Upstart's socket then initctl in the guest (Ubuntu) is talking to Upstart in the host and the host upstart has no idea you installed the couchdb upstart job because that was done in the guest.

So do yourself a favor and either:

- use LXC (not crouton) and Ubuntu 14.04
- properly install Ubuntu onto the Chromebook

Comment: Hi thank you for giving notice to this question.. Do you have a recommended tutorial site in installing this LXC?

Comment: The thing is, I have installed couchdb successfully once, but when Ubuntu rebooted, when I curl localhost:5984 it would then reply could not connect to host..